# Hibernate in AWS Lambdas leads to slow startups

Tags: java, hibernate, aws-lambda, hibernate-mapping

I have some AWS Lambda functions that perform database CRUD operations. I have about 20 persistent classes. My application is Spring-based and uses Hibernate for the ORM.

With 1536MB allocated, my function takes about 16 seconds to run from cold start. According to the logs, most of this time is Hibernate parsing my `hbm.xml` files, building `LoadPlans`, and generally processing metadata.

Since a response time of 16 seconds is far too much, I need ways to speed this up. Is there a way to defer Hibernate's metadata parsing or to do it at compile time?

I've taken a look at the [JPA metamodel](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpamodelgen/1.3/reference/en-US/html_single/) generator, but that seems to be made for building queries at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

> With 1536MB allocated, my function takes about 16 seconds to run from cold start. According to the logs, most of this time is Hibernate parsing my hbm.xml files, building LoadPlans, and generally processing metadata.

It shouldn't take so much time. The reason is other, I think. Probably Hibernate schema validation is enabled.

Comment: Unless schema validation is enabled by default, I've done nothing to turn it on. Further, if I remove the database connection string, it only crashes at the end of this time. Remember that lambdas are not very powerful. On my dev machine the function takes only 7 second.

Answer (score 0):

triggering lambda using cloudWatch can be solution, after first cold start it will be "running" about 40 minutes from last execution, just setup trigger event for lambda each 30-40 minutes.